# rsync recursive on same mount only

Tags: linux, mount, rsync

Hopefully, this simple question has a simple answer.

I want to run **rsync** recursively using the **-r** option, but without descending into a different mount point (file system). i.e. like the **-mount** option with the **find** command, one man page reads, e.g., *“Don't descend directories on other filesystems. An alternate name for **-xdev**, for compatibility with some other versions of **find**.”*

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I believe that you want the `-xx` option:

> **-x, --one-file-system** 
>   This tells rsync to avoid crossing a filesystem boundary when recursing. This does not limit the user's ability to
>   specify items to copy from multiple filesystems, just rsync's
>   recursion through the hierarchy of each directory that the user
>   specified, and also the analogous recursion on the receiving side
>   during deletion. Also keep in mind that rsync treats a lqbindrq mount
>   to the same device as being on the same filesystem.
>
> **If this option is repeated, rsync omits all mount-point directories
>   from the copy. Otherwise, it includes an empty directory at each
>   mount-point it encounters** (using the attributes of the mounted
>   directory because those of the underlying mount-point directory are
>   inaccessible).

The reason I say `-xx` is due to the bolded section (emphasis added).

Comment: Thanks. I must've passed over that a dozen times on the man page. :-)

Comment: No worries, I just used the search function (`/`) and looked for "mount".  Took a few `n`exts.  Glad it works!