# Is `rsync -x` actually safe?

Tags: linux, rsync

I suppose that during its traversal rsync checks whether a directory is a mountpoint, and if not, it descends into it.  However, I'm in a situation where mounts are happening dynamically and the mountpoints are not known beforehand. Will rsync behave properly in this case? In other words, is it atomic?

Comment: I'd use the -xx option. 

On my system Linuxmint 18.04, rsync -x doesn't recognize complicated bind mounts such as `/mnt/data/home` to `/home` and then `/mnt/media_library/Pictures` to `/home/jesse/Pictures` an `rsync -ax /mnt/data/ /backup/drive/` includes all files under `/mnt/data/home/jesse/Pictures`

Using -xx does not (see [this answer for details](https://superuser.com/questions/626141/rsync-recursive-on-same-mount-only))